# Different footers on the pages

Tags: header-footer

I confronted some problems with footers in my doc.
[image]

As far you can see a footer on the first page and a footer on another page, the position of the footers are different. And I have no idea how to fix this.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.15in]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        a4paper,
        tmargin=1.8cm,
        lmargin=1.5cm,
        rmargin=1.5cm,
        bmargin=1.8cm
 }
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Quicksand}
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\fontsize{28}{31}\selectfont}
    \subsectionfont{\fontsize{21}{24}\selectfont}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\usepackage{ifthen}       
        \newif\IfWWW
        \WWWtrue
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!25,
  colback  = #2!10,
  arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=1pt, boxsep=10pt, boxrule=1pt,width=\columnwidth,right=1 pt
  #1,
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{MS Exchange User Manual} % левый верхний колонтитул
\chead{} % центральный верхний
\rhead{{\includegraphics[height=0.96cm, width=4.74cm]{WWW/Screenshots/WWW_fin_GRB.png}}} % правый верхний
\lfoot{{WWW - Visit our Customer Support Hub: \href{https://support.WWW.com}{https://support.WWW.com}}} % левый нижний
\cfoot{} % центральный нижний
\rfoot{} % правый нижний
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % линия под верхним к.
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % линия над нижним к.

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{links}{HTML}{16e5fe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor=16e5fe,
        urlcolor=links
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I don't have any fancyhdr warnings about too small head or foot.

Comment: uploading your preamble in this case would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If only the first page have different footer and all others the same, than define own page style for the first page, for example `\pagestyle{first}` and after `begin{document` use `\thispagestyle{first}\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the footer on the first page is correct but others are not

Comment: You need to define two `\pagestyle`, one for the first page, one for the others. Then use them as I show in my previous comment.